# C# progress bar not updating

Tags: c#, progress

I have a progress bar on my form, I want it to update everytime at the end of a loop.

```
progressBar1.Value += (progressBar1.Maximum/4);
if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```

I have this at the end of my loop, but its not updating as the loop goes, just stays as a solid grey bar...Any tips? Thanks

Comment: can you provide the other code?

Comment: can you provide the whole declaration of progressBar?

Comment: You should put the *relevant* code above, not a link to your entire program in the comments. We just need a short example of code that demonstrates the behavior you're having trouble with.

Comment: Okay, so i have this to reportProgress

     backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i*10);
     Thread.Sleep(10);

and then this to update the bar

         private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            }

Comment: I seem to have got it working now...just took a while.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, and I'll delete it later, but here's an example of minimal, reproducible code

Drop a progress bar and a button on a form, and copy this into the button click event. When you click the button, the progress bar shows progress and then a message box is supposed to let you know when it's done, but instead I'm getting the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = 999;

    while (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        progressBar1.Value += (progressBar1.Maximum / 4);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Done!");
}
```